# Can you create Directories whose name contains a period in windows MSI/Orca.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, orca

Is it possible to create a (valid) Directory table entry in a Windows MSI for a directory containing period characters?

*(for example, the .git directory, or a directory with a semantic-version)*

Ex:

```
# Directory Table in pseudo-code

Directory=TARGETDIR, Directory_Parent=,          DefaultDir=SourceDir
Directory=git_dir,   Directory_Parent=TARGETDIR, DefaultDir=.git
```

The `.` character is assigned special meaning within the `SourceDir` column.

I am aware that formatted columns can escape a character `[\.]` , but DefaultDir is not a formatted column.

Comment: Could you spoof it as a short filename|long filename pair?  Not sure.  Try (for example): gitdir~1.git|.git

Comment: that's brilliant! Thank you - at the very least it passes ICE validation. It also seems to pass validation for semantic-versions (semver~1|0.1.2). I'll need to do a test to make sure it actually installs correctly.

Comment: You're welcome.  Let me know how you get on....

Comment: Both 'gitdir~1|.git' and 'semver~1|0.1.23' install and uninstall perfectly, in addition to passing ICE validation. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a short filename|long filename pair in the DefaultDir column. For example:
gitdir~1.git|.git